# Node + Express API not working in production

Tags: node.js, api, express, heroku, vue.js

I am developing a web application application with a backend that makes calls to IBM Watson's Tone Analyzer web service. My application is being served on Heroku. The app URL: `https://watson-assist.herokuapp.com` and the Github URL: `https://github.com/kevtr0n/WatsonAssist`.

My current stack is:

1. Vue JS Frontend (Vue CLI 3 generated template)
2. Express Backend
3. Node Runtime

I have used Postman to make calls to the URL in production and it returns the correct response. I have made calls to the localhost in development from frontend/Postman and it returns the correct responses. However, when the frontend calls the API I get the follow errors in the Chrome console:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/analyze net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

tone-analyzer:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

What does my frontend view my backend as on Heroku in production?

`http://localhost:5000` or `https://watson-assist.herokuapp.com`

I have tested both and neither work on the frontend.

My frontend POST that calls the API lies in a Vuex action:

```
analyze: (context) => {
  var url = "https://watson-assist.herokuapp.com/analyze";
  var data = { message: context.state.message };

  console.log(`Action:\tanalyze:\nEntrance:\t${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }).then(
    response => response.json(),
    error => console.log(`Action:\tanalyze\nError:\t${error}`)
  ).then(
    res => context.dispatch('updateState', res)
  );
}
```

The backend POST:

```
app.post('/analyze', (req, res) => {

  if (!req.body) { 
    return res.sendStatus(400); 
  }

  var message = req.body.message
  var tone_analyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
    'iam_apikey': $KEY,
    'url': $URL,
    'version': $VER
  });

  var toneParams = {
    tone_input: { 'text': message },
    content_type: 'application/json'
  };

  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tone_analyzer.tone(toneParams, (error, toneAnalysis) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(new Error(error));
      } else {
        resolve(toneAnalysis);
      }
    });
  });

  p
    .then(result => res.send(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('Error', error.message));
})
```

Comment: Does your frontend and backend have the same domains? If not, you need to enable cors for your backend.

Comment: Yes they should have the same domains, my backend serves my frontend at https://watson-assist.herokuapp.com.. it could also be entirely possible I have no idea what I am talking about. I am very new to web dev